# Como substituir uma série de espaços em branco por apenas um em uma string no R?

Tags: r, regex

Como eu faço para substituir uma série de espaços em branco por apenas um, no R?

Por exemplo, suponha que temos uma string:

```
x <- "      non    non    non    non"
```

Quero fazer com que o conteúdo de x seja: " non non non non".

Comment: Não tenho conhecimentos em R, mas a expressão regular para achar os espaços seria `\s*`, aí basta substituir por um espaço.

Comment: Obrigado, encontrei a solução!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duas soluções possíveis:

```
gsub("\\s+", " ", x)
```

e

```
gsub("[[:space:]]+", " ", x)
```

Comment: Falou um + na segunda solução `gsub("[[:space:]]+", " ", x)`